# sublime text 2 browser Build System shortcut

Tags: sublimetext2

I am a windows and Linux user. I've found the solution

```
{
"cmd": ["PATH_TO_YOUR_CHROME", "$file"]
}
```

My question is how to define the shortcut, change it to something else rather than `Ctrl+B` ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Sublime set the user Key Bindings for this. See [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) for how to.

Go to 'Key Bindings - Default' search for '"build"', you will find:

```
{ "keys": ["f7"], "command": "build" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "build" },
```

Copy this to 'Key Bindings - User', and paste. Now you can set the shortcuts to whatever you like. eg.

```
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "build" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+z"], "command": "build" },
```

Comment: Thanks for that. As I created the above Chrome preview via Build system, and how do I define command name? `"command": " WHAT_NAME"`